# Returning multiple values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use a sort of the C#-like `out` or `ref` parameter modifiers with Javascript to do something like this:

```
function myManyReturnFunction(number1, number2, out x, out y) {
    x = number1 * number2;
    y = number1 / number2;

    return true;
}

var height1, height2 = 0;
var check = myManyReturnFunction(1,1, out height1, out hight2);
```

I would like to change the variable's reference as well. So yes, passing an argument by reference.

Comment: so something like pass by reference?

Comment: I believe something along the lines of returning an associative array would be the javascript way to go, but if you're trying to replicate pass by reference this might be interesting: http://sirdarckcat.blogspot.com/2007/07/passing-reference-to-javascript.html

Comment: @kloffy that blog post is full of errors and misunderstandings - I wouldn't rely on it for much of anything

Comment: @Pointy I must admit, I haven't actually tested the code. The explanation seemed reasonable, though. Care to point out the errors?

Comment: @kloffy well it'd take a pretty long post :-) Basically, the author seems not to have known very much about Javascript.  The article is almost 4 years old though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
function myManyReturnFunction(number1, number2) {
    return {
        x: number1 * number2,
        y: number1 / number2
    }
}
```

And you don't need `x` and `y` parameters, simply call:

```
var result = myManyReturnFunction(6, 9);
var x = result.x;
var y = result.y;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an "object"...

```
function getObj(){
var objOut = new Object();
objOut.name = "Smith";
objOut.State = "Arkansas";

return objOut;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you define the 'out' variables in the global scope outside if your function they can be reassigned inside the function with something like this:

```
var height1 = 0, height2 = 0;

function myManyReturnFunction(number1, number2) {
    height1 = number1 * number2;
    height2 = number1 / number2;

    return true;
}


var check = myManyReturnFunction(1,1);
```

You can also create an object, which you can then pass to your function, which can be modified within the function like so:

```
var myValues = {}

function setValues(num1, num2, vals) {
  vals.x = num1 * num2;
  vals.y = num1 / num2;

  return True;
}

setValues(1, 1, myValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to return multiple values in JavaScript. You've always been able to return multiple values in an array:

```
function f() {
    return [1, 2];
}
```

And access them like this:

```
var ret = f();
document.write(ret[0]); // first return value
```

But the syntax is much nicer in JavaScript 1.7 with the addition of destructuring assignment (if you're lucky enough to be targeting an environment guaranteed to support it (e.g. a Firefox extension)):

```
var a, b;
[a, b] = f();
document.write("a is " + a + " b is " + b + "<br>\n");
```

Another option is to return an object literal containing your values:

```
function f() {
    return { one: 1, two: 2 };
}
```

Which can then be accessed by name:

```
var ret = f();
document.write(ret.one + ", " + ret.two);
```

And of course you could do something really horrible like modify global scope or even set properties on the function itself:

```
function f() {
    f.one = 1;
    f.two = 2;
}

f();

document.write(f.one + ", " + f.two);
```

More reading (and the source of some of these examples):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment_(Merge_into_own_page.2fsection)

Answer (score 0):

You can return non-primitive types:

```
function blah() {
  return { name: 'john', age: 23 };
};

var x = blah();
```